Why is CSS flex not working when deployed?
I want my page to be divided in two vertically. This works locally, but not on Chrome when deployed (see screenshots), although it does work on Safari.
Any help appreciated




.container {
  display: flex !important;
  height: 100vh;
  /* Full viewport height */
}

.left-panel,
.right-panel {
  width: 50% !important;
  padding: 20px;
}

.left-panel {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  /* Light background for the description */
  box-shadow: inset -2px 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  /* Divider shadow */
}
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Left Panel: Project Description -->
    <div class="left-panel">
      <h1>Project Description</h1>
      <p>
        Welcome to ...
      </p>
      <p>
        The bot’s core functionality...
      </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Right Panel: AlienBot -->
    <div class="right-panel">
      <h1>Chat with AlienBot</h1>
      <div class="chat-container" id="chat">
        <!-- Messages will be appended here -->
      </div>
      <div id="message-input">
        <input type="text" id="user_input" placeholder="Say something..." />
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>




I've tried adding !important to the container flex. There are no external css styles that might override the stylesheet.

I'm on Mac running Monterey 12.6.1, and this code works on all my browsers. Brave: v 1.70.126
Chrome: v 125.0.6422.113
Safari: 15.6.1
Firefox: 131.0b4 Maybe listing the specific versions of O.S. and browser you're using could be helpful in determining what is causing the issue?

Do you have any reset or global css values set in your css file that could be over writing your css class setting - note it says user-agent setting  for "div" in your screen shot. Also have you tried a "HARD RESET" for the browser cache usually its hold down ctrl + click on reload button? User-agent is built in css style from browser.

You could try adding
flex-direction: row;

in your .container class,
tho I don't now why it doesn't work. maybe you're looking at a different file (a copy of the old state perhaps or cached version), or maybe the browser takes some percent of the space of the website and the 50% for the second div just isn't there.

That's it, thank you!

Try to delete your cache. You probably wrote display block first, and flex after. but the first file downloaded still in cache with display block.
